# Stereoisomers of compounds named tribromocyclobutane

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

[Here](http://groups.chem.ubc.ca/chem260/Stereochemistry1KEY2013.pdf) is the link to the page in which I don't understand the answer to the last question (Question 13). The question states:

> Draw all of the constitutional isomers and stereoisomers of compounds named
>   tribromocyclobutane (all structures must contain a cyclobutane ring).

The following image exists as a part of the answer.

[image]

But why is the following image not part of the answer?

[image]

Are the above two images not diastereomers (hence stereoisomers)?

Comment: The bottom structure doesn't make sense the way you draw the dibromo carbon (non tetrahedral)

Comment: Been reading isomerism for so long that I didn't even care to think about the most basic rules! Thanks for the answer though! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second configuration shown cannot exist simply because of the geometry of the orbitals at the carbon center. The angle between the bromine's (those on the same carbon) is much less than 108° even though there is no forced strain.

Comment: Been reading isomerism for so long that I didn't even care to think about the most basic rules! Thanks for the answer though! :)

Comment: I think another way to make the point is that for identical substituents at the same carbon is a cyclobutane, there is no reason to even use the wedge notation.  Nothing at all is chiral about the dibromo substituted carbon.  And actually, due to symmetry, I don't think there is anything chiral about the singly bromo-substituted carbon either.